# how to send SMS to mobile from Powershell

Tags: powershell, sms, sms-gateway

I want to send a SMS to mobile using powershell.
As we know, we can easily send email using powershell.
In similar way i want to send SMS using powershell.

I tried the following code:-

```
$smtpServer = "zzzz"
$smtpFrom = "xxxx"
$smtpTo = "yyyy@sms.bsnl.in"
$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $smtpfrom, $smtpto
$message.Body="hi"
$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Send($message)
```

**NOTE**
I need to send SMSs to different carriers. So I need to know the SMS gateway for all the sim carriers.
This command is getting executed successfully but i am not recieving any messages. 
I am not sure whther the SMS gateway is correct or not.
Can someone please help in this regard

Comment: You might need to add credential - something like this: `smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("yyyy@sms.bsnl.in", "password")`.

Comment: but with out credentials also am able to send mail as i have already configured that in my SMTP service

Comment: i am able to send email using this code

Comment: Email to SMS gateways are fairly opaque; it can be difficult to determine why a given message makes it through or not, but do know that they are filtered, sometimes aggressively (spam is an even bigger problem when it can cause your phone to blow up with expensive messages), so make sure you're sending through a legitimate and properly set up MTA, not some local mail server or spammy service. It could make all the difference.

Comment: No those all are taken care off still am not getting any messages

Comment: AFAIK you can't just send an SMS message. With anything. You need an account with a service provider and they send the message when you request it. So you'll need to sign up with someone like M-Science and use their APIs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$To = 'xxxxxxxxxx@vtext.com'
$txtSubject = 'Test'
$txtFullMessageText = 'test'
$SMTP = 'SMTPSERVER'
$txtFrom = "$env:COMPUTERNAME@domain.com"

Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Send-MailMessage -To $To -Subject $txtSubject -Body $txtFullMessageText -SmtpServer $SMTP -From $txtFrom
```

**Note:** you will need to enter account credentials to if you SMTP server requires it.

[Here](https://20somethingfinance.com/how-to-send-text-messages-sms-via-email-for-free/) is a list of the different carriers.